# Display a specific variation product attribute count before add to cart button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, product-variations

There is a variable product with the attribute 'Color' and 3 values, white | black | red. I want to display the color count, which is '3' in this case, before add to cart button, I am using the following code and the `$color_count` returns 0.

I have tested the following code, and it will work by adding product attributes via **Products -- Attributes**, then adding the attribute to the product, but I created new product attributes by editing the variable product directly.

How to modify the code and make the `$color_count` returns the correct value, **without adding attributes via Products -- Attributes**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_display_product_variations_count' );
function wc_display_product_variations_count() {
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        $variation_count = count( $variations );
        $color_count = 0;
        foreach( $variations as $variation ) {
            $variation_attributes = $variation['attributes'];
            if( isset( $variation_attributes['attribute_pa_color'] ) ) {
                $color_count++;
            }
        }
        echo '<small>(' . $color_count . ' Colors, ' . $variation_count . ' Variations)</small><br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a little mistake in your code. Find below an enhanced working version:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'wc_display_product_variations_count' );
function wc_display_product_variations_count() {
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        // Here define your product attribute label name (or slug)
        $attribute_name = __('Color', 'woocommerce');

        $variation_attribute = wc_variation_attribute_name( wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $attribute_name ) );
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        $variations_count = count( $variations );
        $attribute_count  = 0; // Initializing
        
        // Loop through variations (arrays)
        foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
            if( isset($variation['attributes'][$variation_attribute]) ) {
                $attribute_count++; 
            }
        }

        // Output
        printf( '<small>(%d %s, %d %s)</small><br>',
            $attribute_count, 
            _n($attribute_name, $attribute_name . 's', $attribute_count, 'woocommerce'),
            $variations_count, 
            _n('Variation', 'Variations', $variations_count, 'woocommerce')
        );
    }
}
```

It should work as required.

Comment: I have tested but the `$attribute_count` still returns 0, here is the screenshot https://ibb.co/G5VHyZV, buy the way, I didn't add attributes through Products--Attributes, I just added attributes from Product data--Attributes while creating the product. Really appreciate for your answer anyway.